# Spring STS - unable to resolve properties

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

This question is not related with spring, but with STS tool suite or with spring eclipse IDE. Given following declaration of the class

```
@Configuration()
@Import({ WebSharedConfig.class, SpringSecurityConfig.class })
@ComponentScan({ "com.finovera.web", "com.finovera.platformServices","com.finovera.authentication" })
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource({ "${FINOVERA_PROPERTIES}" }),
@PropertySource(value = { "${STATIC_OVERRIDE_PROPERTIES}", }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })
@Scope("singleton")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class CabinetConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
}
```

I am seeing following exception in STS plugin (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.finovera.web.config.CabinetConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'FINOVERA_PROPERTIES' in string value "${FINOVERA_PROPERTIES}"
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
```

Error is simple as properties name is passed to JVM when application starts. The application run time code works fine, but STS does not. Lot of functionality missing as main configuration scan fails. Commenting out property sources annotation, everything works fine.

How do I pass property value to STS or convince it to ignore PropertySources annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a limitation in the current implementation. Please file an enhancement request against: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and we can try to fix this for the next release of STS and Spring IDE.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I did log a bug STS-4303 yesterday - but logged it as a bug